# React native - declarar state dentro de una función

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tengo un problema, quiero declarar this.state o state dentro de una función que es exportada por defecto.

Código:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Image, Text, StatusBar, Alert, LayoutAnimation, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

import { Button, Fab } from 'native-base'

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'

import Header from '../components/Header'

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function ProfileScreen(props) {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.name)
  const image = useSelector(state => state.auth.image) + '?type=large'

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Fab
        active={this.state.active}
        direction="up"
        containerStyle={{ }}
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }}
        position="bottomRight"
        onPress={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })}
      >
        <Ionicons name="share" />
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#34A34F' }}>
          <Ionicons name="logo-whatsapp" />
        </Button>
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#3B5998' }}>
          <Ionicons name="logo-facebook" />
        </Button>
        <Button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#DD5144' }}>
          <Ionicons name="mail" />
        </Button>
      </Fab>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
..styles
})
```

Cuando hago algo como esto `state = { active: false }` debajo de la constante image me sale error, mi pregunta es como declarar el estado dentro de una función o fuera, que no sea usando clases ya que si hago eso me sale error en `useSelector()` de la librería `react-redux`

Comment: Deberías importar desde `react` así `import { useState } from 'react'` y la forma de usar el estado sería así: `const [active,setActive] = useState(false);` de esa forma se crea, y cuando quieras cambiar el valor llamas a `setActive(true);`

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas teniendo es que estas intentando usar los estados como se hace en la version antigua de React JS, pero ahora con la nueva version y con los hooks para poder usar un estado en un componente tienes que usar el hook useState y con este hooks podrás crear tantos estados como necesites en todos tus componentes.

Para importar el useState que viene de React es de la siguiente manera.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

Y para hacer uso de useState seria de la siguiente manera.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

Con el estado que acabo de crear funciona de la siguiente maneras, **la variables isLoading devuelve el valor del estado isLoading** y la **variable setIsLoading es una función que sirve para actualizar el estado isLoading y se usaría de la siguiente manera**.

```
setIsLoading(true);
```

Y por últimos cuando creamos un nuevo estado al final cuando ponemos useState() lo que añadimos dentro de los parentesis es el valor default del estado.

De voy a dejar tu código adaptado a los estados con los hooks usando useState para que lo veas funcionando en un código real.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Image, Text, StatusBar, Alert, LayoutAnimation, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Fab } from 'native-base'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function ProfileScreen(props) {
  const [fabActive, setFabActive] = useState(true)
  const [nameUser, setNameUser] = useState("")
  const [imageUser, setImageUSer] = useState("....")

  const user = useSelector(state => nameUser)
  const image = useSelector(state => imageUser) + '?type=large'

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Fab
        active={fabActive}
        direction="up"
        containerStyle={{ }}
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }}
        position="bottomRight"
        onPress={() => setFabActive(!fabActive)}
      >
        <Ionicons name="share" />
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#34A34F' }}>
          <Ionicons name="logo-whatsapp" />
        </Button>
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#3B5998' }}>
          <Ionicons name="logo-facebook" />
        </Button>
        <Button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#DD5144' }}>
          <Ionicons name="mail" />
        </Button>
      </Fab>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
..styles
})
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo Jimmy.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en la tarde probare tu solución, pero lo que yo hice ayer para solucionar eso es crear un componente aparte y que allí si use clases, creo que eso igual funcionaría.